# Concatenating string from UIAlertView text field

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I've got a UIAlertView with a text field (alertView). Let's just say I type in "Asdf" in the UIAlertView text field.

In the first line, I grab the text from that field and create `*myString` from it.

```
NSString *myString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
```

On the 2nd line, I display this string in the NSLog with an addition.

```
NSLog(@"My String is: %@", myString);
```

This displays properly in the NSLog:

> My String is: Asdf

So then on the 3rd line I create an NSString with this addition + my original string (myString). Finally on the 4th line I display this second string in the NSLog.

```
NSString *mySecondString = (@"My String is: %@", myString);
NSLog(@"%@", mySecondString);
```

On the 3rd line (`mySecondString = ...`), I get a warning saying

> Expression result unused

The NSLog for this displays improperly as such:

> Asdf

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple so if you spot something it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That's not how you concatenate strings in Objective-C**
To properly concatenate two `NSString` instances, there are a few options.

Option #1. `+stringWithFormat` class method.

```
NSString *a = @"hello";
NSString *b = @"world";

NSString *c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", a, b];
```

Option #2, `-stringByAppendingString` instance method.

```
NSString *a = @"hello";
NSString *b = @"world";

NSString *c = [a stringByAppendingString:b];
```

In your case, you could use the following.

```
NSString *mySecondString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"My String is:", myString];
```